# Status bar color when navigating to new screen

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using following in my `build()` method of 1st screen to change status bar color and it works fine.

```
// 1st screen's build() method
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
  SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.green),
);
```

However when I navigate to 2nd screen the 1st screen status bar color appears on the 2nd screen too. And in 2nd screen's `build()` method, I am using the same code with different color

```
// 2nd screen's build() method
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
  SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.red),
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the 2nd status bar color before doing the `Navigator.push` to the second screen. Like this

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
  SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.red),
);
await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) => SecondScreen();
));
```

From [Flutter Docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setSystemUIOverlayStyle.html)

> Call this API in code whose lifecycle matches that of the desired system UI styles. For instance, to change the system UI style on a new page, consider calling when pushing/popping a new PageRoute.

Comment: What if you change it back to green before you do the Navigation pop?

Comment: One problem, currently I am having default back button but this way I have to handle everything using WillPopScope. Not a good way to go but had to do. Can you suggest a better way?

Comment: @VolleyBall The appBar contains a "leading" property, Give that property an Icon of arrow back and give it a gesture detector with Navigator.of(context).pop() on pressing that.

Comment: @WaleedArshad I knew it but I was asking for something else.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem and found the solution. The best way is to use **AnnotatedRegion** under **Scaffold** without **AppBar** (`appBar` is null) instead of the function `SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle()` to set the system ui color.

Something like:

```dart
Scaffold(
  body: AnnotatedRegion(
    value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.red) 
    child: MyBodyWidget(),
  ),
);
```

Btw, the `value` can be `SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark` or `SystemUiOverlayStyle.light` if you only want dark or light overlay instead of a color. Note that `statusBarColor` only works in Android so far.

Also note that `appBar` has to be null (absent) for **AnnotatedRegion** to work. You can write your own **MyAppBar** widget easily inside **MyBodyWidget**.

Comment: How to revert back to the original color once we leave the page?

Comment: @lgvaz I haven't tried this technique for some time. But I don't think you need to revert back. The AnnotatedRegion only affects the current Scaffold instance. After leaving the page, the system ui color will depend on whatever the other Scaffold's setting. Please correct me if I am wrong. I will run some code tests when I get time.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong then, the test I ran does not revert back to the original color.

Comment: @lgvaz You are right. If you change the status bar color in the child and then Navigator.pop to its parent screen, AppBar() won't reset the status bar color. So to make it work, you have to make all parent page routes in the navigator stack use AnnotatedRegion. I checked my previous project, which had bottom tabs navigation and used AnnotatedRegion for one bottom tab and the root screen of that tab was using AnnotatedRegion and all its children screens used AnnotatedRegion too. But this doesn't affect other bottom tabs though.

Comment: Yeah, in my case it would be too much trouble to make all other pages use AnnotedRegion. Is there a way to change the color when poping a route?

Answer (score 0):

It has a simple solution.
It is one way of several method.(AnnotatedRegion)

First, top parent page buildcontext in Saffold
 SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, <---- transparent.

and 2nd page of 3rd page ...
if Appbar : Appbar( backgroundcolor: Colors.red <---- want color.

if no Appbar : Scaffold( backgroundcolor: Colors.red <---- want color.

This way,  if you do a navigation pop, Page status color return the background color of Appbar or the background color of the scaffold.

It's my shortcut and I hope it helps.