# AnnotatedRegion for changing statusBarColor

Tags: flutter

I'm using `AnnotatedRegion` to change the system status bar color like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53469650/status-bar-color-when-navigating-to-new-screen/55950102#55950102).

My problem is: After leaving the page, how do I go back to the original color?